# asp.net core 3.1 sendgrid not sending out emails

Tags: asp.net, sendgrid, asp.net-core-3.1

Ive been stuck with this sendgrid not sending emails out. ive tried different API keys, different emails....etc. not getting any errors with the debugger unless im seeing it wrong but, maybe someone can help me understand. This is with ASP.NET CORE 3.1

EDIT: I FIGURED IT OUT.
it was in my email sender class. the "from emailaddress" had to actually be from a real email address. I used the same email used from my sendgrid account.

```
        var msg = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            From = new EmailAddress("VALID EMAIL ADDRESS", "message"),
            Subject = subject,
            PlainTextContent = message,
            HtmlContent = message
        };
```

[image]

Comment: You cut off the most important part of the code, the piece that actually sends the message. Also check SendGrids activity log to see if the request is actually making it through. Maybe your code works fine and they're not sending it for some reason.

Comment: I’ll post better details in the morning. Thanks for the input

Comment: You might want to use the `async / await` keywords, if you denote methods as `Task SendEmailAsync`

Comment: @rahmikg: did you find a solution to this